# Flutter - draggable text when oveflow in Row

Tags: flutter, overflow, draggable

I'm making a simple task app, which gets tasks from server api and then I am able to change their state from mobile.
I have a list of task items. Each item is made from Column, which has two rows (one is empty for now).
My question is - it is possible to make the text dragable, so i can drag the overflown text (to left) and see the rest of it (and then back to right)? I have found some solutions which used animations to move the text all the time. I just wanna control it with my finger.

Here is my simplified code:

```
return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TaskDetailScreen.routeName,
                        arguments: task.id);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    task.id + ' - ' + task.name,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    softWrap: false,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ButtonTheme(
                buttonColor: Color(0xff24a0ed),
                minWidth: 100,
                child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'Dokončit',
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          task.toggleActiveStatus(context);
                        },
                      ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      color: Color(0xffcfcfcf),
    );
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Answer (score 1):

You could try a number of solutions for this including a GestureDetector to change the Row into a Wrap widget when it finds a pan down occurring.